# Spring @Qualifier and @Autowire doesn't work

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired

[Whole Source Code has the problem below](https://kldp.org/files/dbimp.test_.zip)

I'm working with two databases. So I added two datasources with different name. When I thought I inject proper datasource. I got unexpected error below. what's wrong with my codes?

my application.yml file

```
<pre>
spring:
  datasource:
    source:
      driver-class-name: org.sqlite.JDBC
      url: jdbc:sqlite::resources/db/StudentCarrer.db3
    destination:
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      url: jdbc:mysql://nas4:3306/cku
      username: cku
      password: cku
</pre>
```

my DBConfig.java file

```
<pre>
@Configuration
public class DBConfig {

    @Bean(name = "srcDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.source")
    public DataSource srcDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "srcJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate srcJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("srcDataSource") DataSource srcDataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(srcDataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "dstDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.destination")
    public DataSource dstDataSource() {
    return  DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dstJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate dstJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dstDataSource") DataSource dstDataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dstDataSource);
    }
}
</pre>
```

my DBImporter.java file

```
<pre>
@Component
public class DBImporter {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired @Qualifier("srcDataSource")
    public DataSource srcDataSource;

    @Autowired @Qualifier("srcJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate srcJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired @Qualifier("dstDataSource")
    public DataSource dstDataSource;

    @Autowired @Qualifier("dstJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate dstJdbcTemplate;
}
</pre>
```

And I got this ERROR.

```
<pre>
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field srcDataSource in com.cku.assmt.dbimp.DBImporter required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - srcDataSource: defined by method 'srcDataSource' in class path resource [com/cku/assmt/dbimp/DBConfig.class]
    - dstDataSource: defined by method 'dstDataSource' in class path resource [com/cku/assmt/dbimp/DBConfig.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
</pre>
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you are correctly importing `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier` inside of `DbImporter`? This really doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: This is the code with the problem. https://kldp.org/files/dbimp.test_.zip

Comment: Yea, I'm not clicking that. Add it to your post if you want people to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using @Bean(name = "myName"), use two annotations on the method: @Bean @Qualifier("myName")

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I got the same error. This is the whole project. https://kldp.org/files/dbimp.test_.zip